# How do I delete a curse window in python and restore background window?

Tags: python, window, curses

I'm working on python curses and I have an initial window with initscr(). Then I create several new windows to overlap it, I want to know if I can delete these windows and restore the standard screen without having to refill it. Is there a way? Could someone tell me the difference between a window, subwindow, pad and sub pad.

I have this code:

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
####Then I fill it with random letters
stdscr.refresh()
newwin=curses.newwin(10,20,5,5)
newwin.touchwin()
newwin.refresh()

####I want to delete newwin here so that if I write stdscr.refresh() newwin won't appear

stdscr.touchwin()
stdscr.refresh()

####And here it should appear as if no window was created.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This, e.g, should work:

```
import curses

def fillwin(w, c):
    y, x = w.getmaxyx()
    s = c * (x - 1)
    for l in range(y):
        w.addstr(l, 0, s)

def main(stdscr):
    fillwin(stdscr, 'S')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

    newwin=curses.newwin(10,20,5,5)
    fillwin(newwin, 'w')
    newwin.touchwin()
    newwin.refresh()
    newwin.getch()
    del newwin

    stdscr.touchwin()
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

This fills the terminal with 'S'; at any keystoke, it fills the window with 'w'; at the next keystroke, it removes the window and show the stdscr again, so it's again all-'S'; at the next keystroke, the script ends and the terminal goes back to normal.  Isn't this working for you?  Or do you actually want something different...?

Comment: Hey! thanks :D, well the only thing I really needed was de "del" I was not sure how to delete the windows, and it worked inside the code I had, thanks really.

Comment: I was wandering - could one use `newwin = None`,instead of `del newwin` (so one could test for `newwin`, without raising `UnboundLocalError` or similar)? That is, would the Python garbage collector properly dispose of the `newwin` resources, if just `newwin = None` is specified?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, "del newwin" is functionally equivalent to "newwin = None".  That is, "del" does not actually *delete* newwin; it merely cleans up that particular reference, reducing its reference count by one.

Comment: Deleting newwin has no effect (see manpage for [delwin](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-delwin)).  The following touchwin/refresh of stdscr is all that's actually effective.