# (n)curses pad in python not working

Tags: python, ncurses

I cannot seem to get ncurses pads to work in python (2.6, 2.7, and 3.2). Using code directly off of http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html I even cannot get it to work. Non-pad code works perfectly.

```
import curses

def func(scr):
    pad = curses.newpad(100, 100)
    pad.addstr(0,0, "Testing")

    #  Displays a section of the pad in the middle of the screen
    pad.refresh( 0,0, 5,5, 10,10)

    scr.refresh()
    scr.getch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(func)
```

What can the issue be? Removing the pad (and changing pad to scr) works fine

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu 12.04 for 2.7 and 3.2 and Debian 6.0 for 2.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're overwriting the pad.  Try calling the `getch` method from the `pad` object instead of the main window object `scr` and delete the `scr.refresh`.

Comment: You want to be reading in the context of the pad window rather than from the base window.  A pad window is normally a temporary sub-window overlaying another window.